# Water heater still won't heat after replacing thermostat and elements

Tags: water, water-heater

I have replaced both thermostats and elements in a Reliance water heater which
checks out 120v at each screw in thermostats and each side of elements still will not heat. What else can I do?

Comment: What model heater is this? Also, is the thing pulling current? (Use a clampmeter on one of the hot lines to check.)  And is that 120V hot-to-hot or hot-to-chassis?

Comment: Alternative to clampmeter is to watch electric meter while you turn the breaker on and off; it should spin faster/slower.

Answer (score 1):

With your volt meter check the voltage at both terminal screws at the same time (screw to screw ) the voltage should be about 230 volts. If it is not 230 volts then you probably have one leg of the 230 volt line open or not energized. Try shutting off the circuit breaker for the water heater and turning back on. If no change you may have a bad circuit breaker or broken wire.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!  After much checking, I did find a bad spot in the wiring that was not letting full current through.